# Update mongo array elements by index with c-driver

Tags: mongodb

To update elements of a mongo array, I was using syntax like:

```
{"$set":{"a.0":1238},{"a.1":402}}
```

Or, more accurately, I was using the C-driver function calls that I think are equivalent to that.  This seemed to work fine, but when I look at the object in MongoHub, I see:

```
a: {"0":1238,"1":402}
```

instead of:

```
a: [1238,402]
```

Does anyone know what is proper syntax to access array elements by index with C-driver?  What I am doing now serves my immediate purpose, but I am not sure if there are significant performance differences.  Also, I might later need to use operations that require true array.

Comment: Might be wrong but have you tried syntax like `{"$set":{"a": {1238, 402}}}`

Comment: @Hank: that's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a field didn't exist, then this dot-notation query will create it as a hash (object) and assign values to keys of that hash. If field exists and is an array, it will behave as you expect. See this session.

```
> db.arrays.insert({});
> db.arrays.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518c8b58713e4dbadbfb9f") }
> db.arrays.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518c8b58713e4dbadbfb9f") }, {$set: {"a.0": 123}});
> db.arrays.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518c8b58713e4dbadbfb9f"), "a" : { "0" : 123 } }


> db.arrays.insert({a: []})
> db.arrays.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518c8b58713e4dbadbfb9f"), "a" : { "0" : 123 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518cca58713e4dbadbfba0"), "a" : [ ] }
> db.arrays.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518cca58713e4dbadbfba0") }, {$set: {"a.0": 123}});
> db.arrays.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518c8b58713e4dbadbfb9f"), "a" : { "0" : 123 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f518cca58713e4dbadbfba0"), "a" : [ 123 ] }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  As long as I use explicit array syntax to initialize the field, then subsequent updates work.