# Replace value in array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am  using Mongodb C# official driver. I want to change a particular value in an array with some other value. The array contains list of values. For eg.

```
{ 
   _id: id1,
   values: [23, 78, 20]
}
```

I want suppose to replace 23 by 25. 
I know one answer if it is right.
First I pull that element and then push other. But the problem is that if the element is not present then also push will insert the element. Secondly, it will change the position and insert the element at the end.
Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Read about positional operator

Comment: I have read but all examples  are about incrementing the value.

Comment: well, swap `$inc` for `$set` and you're good to go.

Comment: I have done it. But it inserts the null in that array..

Comment: I just did it and it worked as expected. There's problem in your code.

Comment: I am using Update.set("values.$.23","20");

Comment: please tell me the correct way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this:

```
db.collection.update({_id: id1, values: 23}, {$set: {'values.$': 25}})
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `_id` to this answer. Otherwise you will update the first document with a `value` of 23, which is not what you want.

Comment: @GatesVP: Thanks it works. But what to do if I want each occurence of 23 to be replaced by certain number. $ works for first matched.

Comment: @HimaniTalesara: you can run this update repeatedly, or you can fetch the document to the app, modify it there and save back.

Comment: `db.collection.update({values:23}, {$set: {'values.$': 25}}, false, true)` That extra `false` is "do not upsert". That extra `true` is "perform this update multiple times".

Comment: @GatesVP: that won't work if he needs to replace multiple values in the same document. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work with you

```
db.collection.update({ "_id" : id1 }, {$set: {"values.0": 23}});
```

check this post as well 
[Update mongo array elements by index with c-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542635/update-mongo-array-elements-by-index-with-c-driver)